# Get youtube video url form webpage source

Tags: html, url, youtube

Is it possible to get the download URL of currently playing video from source of YouTube webpage?Thanks in advance.Please help me.

Actually I have a downloader but it is not working now.When I have tried with the URL provided by the downloader in browser it returns an error page says "Access to the webpage was denied".The Url that I got for a video is as 
    **" http://r14---sn-h557snel.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?gcr=in&ip=121.241.181.70&upn=OOcjKEO_S6I&cp=U0hUTFZQT19KU0NONF9OSlNGOmFRT2JSUUs2bDVi&ipbits=8&fexp=900148,920704,912806,928001,922403,922405,929901,913605,929104,913546,913556,908496,920201,913302,919009,911116,901451,902556&ms=au&mt=1357625350&mv=m&id=31a79fcdbfc6c2f6&sparams=cp,gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&expire=1357651559&itag=18&key=yt1&newshard=yes&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&sver=3"**

Few months before the format of URL was 
    **" http://o-o---preferred---sn-h557snes---v24---lscache3.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=AmmxhSpq470&sparams=cp,gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&fexp=917013,906437,916626,922401,920704,912806,927201,925706,922403,913546,913556,916805,920201,901451&ms=au&expire=1353668177&itag=18&ipbits=8&gcr=in&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&mt=1353646087&ip=121.241.181.70&mv=m&source=youtube&key=yt1&cp=U0hUSFZRVl9MUUNONF9OS1pCOmhtUTVMak5oTVNy&id=c429fa5466ee9447&newshard=yes "**

So I don't know whether the downloader gives the correct URL. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

I have written a simple python code that can fetch youtube href from html code.
hope it can help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

pattern = '.*<(iframe|param).*(src|value)="(?P<link>http://www.youtube.com/(embed|v)/[a-zA-Z0-9/\.\?&;=\+_-]+);?.*".*>.*</(iframe|param)>.*'

action = re.compile(pattern)
result = action.findall('<div><iframe.....></iframe><param......></param></div>')

print result
```

https://gist.github.com/Mortezaipo/5707738

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I looked around and I couldn't find a way to directly download the source file from the youtube link. There are some guides out there but they all are around 2009; and since youtube changes their code a lot currently none of them work.

Although there are many websites, addons, apps that allow you to download videos; but I do not think they work from a code from the link. Since to watch a video you have to temporarily download it I think they all use a method of opening the page, playing(downloading) the video and actually saving it. I would list those websites and addons but since those sources are not that hard to find; I assume you are trying to build your own downloader and not use one that is already out there.

Also on another note if you could somehow get a link to a videos source file. I am sure youtube has permissions blocked access on all folders and files on their backend for security measures; only allowing those files to be forwarded and displayed on the actual player page. And if you think embedded videos would somehow work they still just make a request to youtube which youtube then gives back video-feed-data so there still is no direct connection to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the player API https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

`player.getVideoUrl():String`

Returns the YouTube.com URL for the currently loaded/playing video.

Comment: It's not true, the result it's always: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video id>